# Parcel Fabric visible in ArcCatalog but not in Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, parcel, parcel-fabric

I'm new to Pro and very new to parcel fabrics.  I followed some instructions I found online and ran an Append on a feature class to create a parcel fabric.  It said it was successful, and in Arc Catalog I can see all of the new feature classes in the feature dataset.  However, when I try and add the parcel fabric to Pro it is not there to add.  I was able to drag the feature dataset from the Pro catalog into the table of contents but the parcel fabric isn't in it.

Comment: which version? you did not mention the upgrade parcel fabric (for pro) https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/data/parcel-editing/upgradeparcelfabric.htm

Answer (score 0):

You have to then 'add parcel type' and append parcel polygons into that. You should then see those when you view the fabric.